# Perl script - expected ' " ' or JSON isn't valid

Tags: json, perl

Okay, I have this method:

```
sub config {
my $filename = 'perl_config.txt';
my $json_text = do {
    open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename)
        or die("Can't open the file!");
    local $/;
    <$json_fh>
};
my $json = JSON->new;

my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

};
```

Terminal (interpreter rather ;) ) says:

```
'"' expected, at character offset 115 (before "}") at ./proj_perl.pl line 25
```

Line 25 indicates on `my $data = $json->decode($json_text);`

EDIT: I've edited my question and cut unnecessary code. I still don't know what's wrong.
My JSON file is:

```
{
"local_host": "localhost",
"local_port": "6000",
"save_dir": "received_files",
"my_data": "my_data.txt",
}
```

Comment: Show your JSON file. It's probably malformed.

Comment: Definitely malformed :)

Comment: {
  "local_host": "localhost",
  "local_port": "6000",
  "save_dir": "received_files",
  "my_data": "my_data.txt",
}

Comment: Remove the final comma (after `"my_data.txt"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid JSON:

```js
{
"local_host": "localhost",
"local_port": "6000",
"save_dir": "received_files",
"my_data": "my_data.txt",
}
```

JSON forbids the final comma. Javascript allows it (I think?), but JSON is based on a subset of Javascript.

JSON::PP and JSON::XS (the two backends supported by the Perl JSON module) each have a relaxed mode where they relax a few of JSON's syntactic restrictions, including this one.

```perl
my $json = JSON->new->relaxed(1);
```

So either fix your JSON or use relaxed mode to parse it.